# Merging videos. multiple overlays and audio in one step

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a process that I run hourly to update a 60 sec weather video.

I combine a background video with a generated m4a audio track, scrolling text and separate top and bottom overlays.

I need all of this in an mp4 and in a TLS (m3u8) format.

Right now I do this 3 ffmpeg consecutive sessions and end up with a rendered 720p mp4.

Then I run a 4th ffpmeg session to convert the the mp4 to a TLS version (I need both mp4 and m3u8.)

I am doing this in 4 ffmpeg runs because I haven’t figured out how to combine the filters and do it in less.

When I try an combine this, I lose either the overlays or the text. I can't get it all to come out in one session. I've tried comma separating within the filters but I haven't found the right combination.

Any assistance in showing me how to combine this work and reduce the number of runs would be greatly appreciated.

This runs on a Centos 7 box with ffmpeg version 3.4.1.

```
#
# Step 1: Combine background video with audio and scrolling text
#
ffmpeg -i /video/weather/media/sunnybeach.mp4 \
-i /video/weather/prod/currentweather.m4a \
-i /video/weather/media/weather-lower-third1.png \
-map 2:v:0 -map 1:a:0 -strict -2 \
-filter_complex  "[0]split[txt][orig];[txt]drawtext=fontfile=/var/www/vhosts/30a.tv/httpdocs/openx/lib/pear/Image/Canvas/Fonts/arial.ttf:fontsize=80:fontcolor=white:x=(w-text_w)/2+20:y=h-70*t:textfile=/video/weather/prod/currentweather.txt:bordercolor=black:borderw=2[txt];[orig]crop=iw:50:0:0[orig];[txt][orig]overlay” \
-t 60 -c:v libx264 -y -s hd720  -loglevel quiet /video/weather/prod/currentweather.mp4 2>&1 >> /dev/null

if [ $? != 0 ]; then echo fail step 1; exit 1;fi

#
# Step 2: now overlay current lowerthird
#
ffmpeg -i /video/weather/prod/currentweather.mp4 \
-i /video/weather/media/weather-lower-third1.png \
-strict -2 -filter_complex  "[0:v][1:v]overlay" -c:a copy -y  \
-loglevel quiet $FKWI/currentweather1.mp4 2>&1 >> /dev/null

if [ $? != 0 ]; then echo fail step 2; exit 1;fi

#
# Step 3: now overlay current topbanner
#
ffmpeg -i $FKWI/currentweather1.mp4 \
-i /video/weather/media/weather-top-banner.png \
-strict -2 -filter_complex  "[0:v][1:v]overlay" -c:a copy -y  \
-loglevel quiet $FKWI/currentweather.mp4 2>&1 >> /dev/null

if [ $? != 0 ]; then echo fail step 3; exit 1;fi

#
# Step 4: Now make TLS version
#

cd $FKWI/httpdocs/weather
RES1=`/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i $FKWI/httpdocs/currentweather.mp4 \
-profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -s 1280x720 \
-c:a aac -ar 48000 -g 60 -start_number 0 \
-hls_time 6 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls \
-hls_base_url "http://$URL.com/weather/" \
-hls_segment_filename "video%04d.ts" \
-strict -2   -loglevel quiet "currentweather.m3u8" 2>&1>>/dev/null `

if [ $? != 0 ]; then echo fail step 4; exit 1;fi
```

This code yields both videos fine, but it takes 4 runs and I need it to happen in less runs.